# Seekbar Progress Drawable Resizing different in API 22 vs API 23

Tags: java, android, xml, android-linearlayout, android-seekbar

I'm using this [library](https://github.com/h6ah4i/android-verticalseekbar) for `VerticalSeekBars` in my Android application. In my app, I'm laying multiple vertical seekbars horizontally (like about 10-15?) using `LinearLayout` and `layout_weight` properites. In addition, I'm using a thumb that is supposed to be bigger than the progress (essentially laying on top of the progress) and a custom drawable for the progress as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:id="@android:id/background"
              android:height="10dp"
              android:gravity="center_vertical">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
             <corners android:radius="500dp"/>
             <solid android:color="#000000"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

On API 23 (which I believe is Marshmallow?), everything lines up correctly and resizing properly across different screen sizes. Awesome. However, on API 22 and below, the progress drawable doesn't adjust itself; instead, it increases it size to have the seekbar thumb fit inside the progress. I've tried to resize the drawable in my code but that still doesn't do anything either. I have drawn it out to show what I mean:

[image: Picture example - excuse my poor drawing skills :(]

How do I get API 22/below to match the same behavior API 23 is achieving with the seekbar?

Here's an example of my `VerticalSeekBar` setup:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <com.h6ah4i.android.widget.verticalseekbar.VerticalSeekBarWrapper
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.5">

            <com.h6ah4i.android.widget.verticalseekbar.VerticalSeekBar
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:max="100"
                android:progress="50"
                app:seekBarRotation="CW270"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_track"
                android:splitTrack="false"/>

    </com.h6ah4i.android.widget.verticalseekbar.VerticalSeekBarWrapper>

           <com.h6ah4i.android.widget.verticalseekbar.VerticalSeekBarWrapper
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.5">

            <com.h6ah4i.android.widget.verticalseekbar.VerticalSeekBar
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:max="100"
                android:progress="50"
                app:seekBarRotation="CW270"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_track"
                android:splitTrack="false"/>

    </com.h6ah4i.android.widget.verticalseekbar.VerticalSeekBarWrapper>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `maxHeight` like this:

```
<com.h6ah4i.android.widget.verticalseekbar.VerticalSeekBar
        ...
        android:maxHeight="2dp"
        .../>
```

Comment: This is the right answer... can't believe I didn't think about this property earlier! The +50 bounty is yours when 21 hours are up ;)